# jQuery data() vs attr(data)

Tags: jquery

I would like to know the difference between saving data to an element using `$(element).data({'foo' : 'bar'})` vs `$(element).attr({ 'data-foo' : 'bar' })`. And which of the two method would be best to use when saving a large amount of data in to an element? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$.data` is used for ***storing*** information with respect to an element:

[Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. Returns
>   the value that was set.

On the other hand, `attr` is used to manipulate ***attributes*** of an element.

From your question, you seem to store the data, you should use `$.data` in that case.

[data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) are a feature of HTML5

#### Performance

.data() seems to be much more performance friendly according to [this](https://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/22)

I also find it cleaner since it's not visible for everyone in page source.

Comment: Im saving an object using JSON.stringify. The data() method can be used to fetch html5 data attributes saved using the .attr() as well. But i suppose using data() would be better.

When using `data`, where is it stored? It doesnt show up as a data attribute on the element

Comment: @Johan: With `$.data` attribs won't be added to element since it is not for attributes but data. As for storing, I believe jQuery stores it internally in some object.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Do you know if IE7 has any problem with data()?

Comment: @Johan: I haven't worked using it with IE7 but you can try it out. I think since jQuery does work for browsers till IE6, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say data, because that is what it was meant to do.  It supports the exact type of functionality you are trying to implement.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/