# How to get updated option attribute in selectbox after ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select-box where a user can pick a value which populates a text-box and the user can edit the value (with Ajax). 
Every option in the selectbox has an id and a data-critical attribute. I use the JQuery 'change' event handler to populate a textbox with the value in the data-critical.

```
<select id="actions">
  <option id="p0" data-critical="100"  value="0">Optie 0</option>
  <option id="p1" data-critical="120"  value="1">Optie 1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="editcritical" />

$("#actions").change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

  $("#editcritical").val(selected.data('critical'));
});

ajax-success: function(data){
  $("#p" + data.p.id).attr("data-critical", data.p.critical);
}
```

On Ajax success the data-critical value is changed, but when I select the option again, the old value is displayed in the text-box. I tried to use the Live method, but nothing happened. Firebug shows the updated value in data-critical.

Any suggestions to show the updated value in the text-box?

Comment: please post you ajax code that change `data-critical`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#actions").change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

  $("#editcritical").val(selected.attr('data-critical'));
});
```

Within you success function you should try:

```
success: function(data){
  $("#p" + data.p.id).data("critical", data.p.critical);
}
```

Read [jQuery data() vs attr(data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444679/jquery-data-vs-attrdata) to know more.

Comment: I tried it, but nope. I can set the textbox with the value from the data-critical attr, but only the not updated value.

Comment: okay, your last update did the trick! Thanks. Do you know why it is wrong to use attr instead data?

Comment: @cooxie I've shared a link in my question, please see that

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with:

```
$("#editcritical").attr("data-critical");
```

?

Comment: I can get and update the value from data-critical. The problem is when the data-critical value is changed after the Ajax call, and I select the option again with the updated data-critical value, the older value is shown in the text-box instead of the new value.

Comment: Is your further code in the .done/.success-method of the ajax call?

Comment: That's why you should replace $("#editcritical").val(selected.data('critical')); with $("#editcritical").attr("data-critical"); as suggested.

Comment: @Abhijit: #editcritical doesn't has an attr 'data-critical', data-critical is an attr from the option from the selectbox

Comment: @cooxie Sorry, I did not notice the id's of select or option, just was referring to using attr instead of data.