# Different jQuery UI behavior in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a very simple calendar. When clicking any date a jQuery dialog gets opened, the user clicks a button, the dialog closes, the clicked button's value gets appended to the clicked element and after that all clicked elements get saved to an array.

I have created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qaxoboroge/edit?html,js,console,output).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="2016-11-01" class="cal_clean_active">Click me</a>
        <div id="dialog"></div>
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

js:

```
$('.cal_clean_active').click(function(e) {
  var that = $(this); 
  var dates = new Array();

  that.toggleClass('clicked');

  $('#dialog').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Vormittags (bis 12:00 Uhr)": function() {
        that.attr('slot','vormittags');
        console.log(that.attr('slot'));
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
      $('.clicked').each(function(i, val) { 
        dates.push(val.id + '|' + val.slot);
      });
        console.log(dates);
    }
  });
});
```

In Chrome everything works as expected (Console output is `2016-11-01|vormittags`) in every other tested Browser (Firefox, Edge, IE) the console output is `2016-11-01|undefined`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `$(val).attr("slot")`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the job. I still don't understand why I can't access the property `slot` like I can access the propery `id`.

Comment: Slot is not a standard property for an element as far as I know, so it is not standard included in the property list of an element in most browsers. In this case it would probably be cleaner to use the jQuery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) handler though.

Comment: Please post your comment as answer so I can vote it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that slot is not a standard attribute for an element. In most browsers, it is hence not included in the standard properties of an element (like `element.value` or `element.id`). Chrome seems to handle this situation differently than the other browsers.

### Two bad solutions

A solution would be to change:

```
dates.push(val.id + '|' + val.slot);
```

to

```
dates.push(val.id + '|' + $(val).attr('slot'));`.
```

Another - plain javascript - solution could be to use the javascript `getAttribute()` method. This would work because in the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/attr.js) custom attributes are set with this line:

```
elem.setAttribute( name, value + "" ); //from the jQuery source code
```

Thus making it possible to also read them with [element.getAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp). Your line would then look like this:

```
dates.push(val.id + '|' + val.getAttribute("slot"));
```

### The better solution

This might all work, but it still is not considered **good code**. In your code the attribute slot is used to store data. From the [.data() jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444703/1493235)):

> Store arbitrary **data** associated with the specified element. Returns the value that was set.

$.attr() on the contrary is used to manipulate **attributes**, like id, value or type. The clean way of solving this problem would be:

```
$('.cal_clean_active').click(function(e) {
  var that = $(this); 
  var dates = new Array();

  that.toggleClass('clicked');

  $('#dialog').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Vormittags (bis 12:00 Uhr)": function() {
        that.data('slot','vormittags'); //Not the use of data
        console.log(that.data('slot'));
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
      $('.clicked').each(function(i, val) { 
        dates.push(val.id + '|' + $(val).data("slot")); //Also note it here
      });
        console.log(dates);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also replaced `.attr()` with `.data()` as you suggested.

Comment: Included it in my answer.